# Agent Oriented Programming code sample

Tags: agent

I'm currently studying Agent Oriented Programming,
And I'm having trouble about finding sample code in any language that is written to demonstrate the idea in real programming modele.

Can any one provide a link where a simple code is written to demonstrate the ideas of AOP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, let's try to have a common understanding of what is AOP. From "Agent-oriented programming" paper written by Yoav Shoham (1993) we have:

> Agent-oriented programming (AOP), can be viewed as a specialization of
>   object-oriented programming. The state of an agent consists of
>   components such as beliefs, decisions, capabilities, and obligations;
>   for this reason the state of an agent is called its mental state. The
>   mental state of agents is described formally in an extension of
>   standard epistemic logics: beside temporalizing the knowledge and
>   belief operators, AOP introduces operators for obligation, decision,
>   and capability. Agents are controlled by agent programs, which include
>   primitives for communicating with other agents. In the spirit of
>   speech act theory, each communication primitive is of a certain type:
>   informing, requesting, offering, and so on.

A good implementation of this concept is Jason, which is richly explained in the book "Programming Multi-Agent Systems in AgentSpeak using Jason" written by Rafael H. Bordini, Jomi Fred Hübner and Michael Wooldridge (2007).

An application to see how would be an AOP could be this small app: 
https://github.com/cleberjamaral/beersponsor

In this simple app there are 3 agents, a robot, an owner (of the robot) and a sponsor. The idea is that the owner want to drink beer and a robot brings all the beer he wants. But after some deliveries the refrigerator run out of beers, so, a Java IDE is launched and the user can click to sponsoring beer to this lazy guy.

To run it you can download Jason and run JEdit (Java -jar JEdit.jar), which is a programming IDE for Jason.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/jason/

You can have more details about this simple implementation here: http://jasonagents.blogspot.com.br/2015/09/exemplo-de-integracao-com-interface.html